# Deleting Contact in SF Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to use this API call www.exacttargetapis.com/contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=ids to delete contacts.It Gives This Error Message
"message": "The Contact Delete operation is not currently enabled."

This is the Request I sent

```
    POST /contacts/v1/contacts/actions/delete?type=ids HTTP/1.1
Host: www.exacttargetapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer MyToken
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
  "values": [
    "38891595"
  ],
  "DeleteOperationType": "ContactAndAttributes"
}
```

the Response I'm getting :

```
{
    "operationInitiated": false,
    "operationID": 17,
    "requestServiceMessageID": "1c5bef62-edbc-49b2-9644-571a890975f8",
    "responseDateTime": "2017-11-23T05:27:21.224657-06:00",
    "hasErrors": true,
    "resultMessages": [
        {
            "resultType": "Operational",
            "resultClass": "Error",
            "resultCode": "OperationDisabled",
            "message": "The Contact Delete operation is not currently enabled. "
        }
    ],
    "serviceMessageID": "db0403a2-4044-480a-b22f-ae154e2985af"
}
```

Could someone tell me how to enable Contact Delete Operation?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create a case to the MC support asking for the "Contact Delete Operation by API" functionality.